# Multi-user Bibliographic Management for Dropbox

Tags: document-management, dropbox

I'm looking for bibliographic/citation management software that can be used in conjunction with a Dropbox business account with multiple shared folders and multiple users.

I've perused: Xotero, Papers, Mendeley and EndNote. EndNote, Mendeley and Xotero do not *really* provide Dropbox support. There are articles out there regarding "symlinks" but that falls apart with multiple users / concurrent logins.

Dropbox is a requirement.

I'm trying to avoid rolling my own software. Does anyone know of an application like EndNote, Papers etc that works with Dropbox business?

**Edit:** A caveat here is that I do not need technical / programming / software consulting help. I haven't been able to find anything that fits my criteria and was hoping that someone else could confirm or reject my findings (with fingers crossed that there's a solution available that I've overlooked - even if outside the box.) Thanks!

Comment: Could you please give an example user story describing one scenario that would work with your dream software, but fails with the tools you cited? Thank you!

Comment: Also, do you have a budget? And what are your operating systems?

Comment: I'm just looking for *any* citation / bibliographic management software that meets the following criteria: 1) can use dropbox as its document repository, 2) has multiple users that can access the documents, concurrently and 3) does the normal stuff that any of the other aforementioned citation management software does.

Comment: None of Xotero, Papers, Mendeley or EndNote, provide the combination of "dropbox" and "multiuser."